# Google Sheet Filter and Match (List the label where a name exist.)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google, google-sheets-filter

I have 4 game columns that contain the names of the players. I want to list the games of a particular player.

```
     A.         B.          C.          D
Basketball   Bowling     Billiards   Badminton
----------   -------     ---------   ---------
John         Paul        Mark        Paul
Paul         Robert      James       Chris
Matt         Wesley      Brad        Dexter
```

Now I want to create a formula and list all the games Paul played. Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now this looks good!!! (yet complicated)

1. create 2 named ranges: 1: lst_hds (range(A1:D1) to contain the game names, 2: lst_db (range(A3:D5)) to contain the players.
2. still in B10 the name you search for...
3. now copy-paste:
   `=arrayformula( if(mid( text(sum( ( if( lst_db=$B$10, 10^(column(lst_db)-1),0) ) ),"0000") ,columns(lst_hds)+1-COLUMN(lst_hds),1)="1",lst_hds,"") )`

now this is much easier to expand by adjusting the ranges!!!
Off-course you can transpose it to get vertical list.

I keep the 1st formula for reference:

```
=FILTER(A1:D1,{countif(A3:A5,B10),countif(B3:B5,B10),countif(C3:C5,B10),COUNTIF(D3:D5,B10)})
```

hope it helps

**EDIT Oct 2021**
Just added one even simpler solution (actually two but very similar). Let's see them:

1. `=arrayformula( if( mmult( {1,1,1}, arrayformula( if(A3:D5=$B$10,1,0) ) )=1,A1:D1,""))`
   ... or *=arrayformula( if( mmult( {1,1,1}, arrayformula( if(lst_db=$B$10,1,0) ) )=1,lst_hds,""))* with our lists! Expand with lists as they grow and Adjust only the {1,1,1} array according to ROWs
2. using Filter and thus getting only the results (without empty cells in between) `=filter(lst_hds, mmult({1,1,1}, ( if(lst_db=$B$10,1,0) ) )=1)`
   again adjust {1,1,1} according to ROWs

Comment: Hi Apostolos55! Thank you for your reply.

For anyone who wants to display the results vertically, add TRANSPOSE at the beginning and open-close the whole formula of Apostolos55.

Thanks for the help, again! I appreciate it.